# How do you sum each row using multiple columns with SQL without it aggregating data?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I'm running my query below to pull out data and there are 3 columns I'm looking to SUM. However, it aggregates the data into one output instead of outputting it for each row it pulled from.

See the second select statement, how do I separate the data?

```
SELECT a.RTL_TRAN_ID, b.LINEITM_SEQ, b.BEGIN_DATE_TIMESTAMP, b.ITEM_ID, b.ITEM_STYLE_ID, b.ITEM_QUANTITY, b.ITEM_BASE_UNIT_PRICE, b.ITEM_UNIT_PRICE, b.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT, x.RTL_LOC_ID
FROM CMP_PROMO_TRAN_RESULT AS a
JOIN TRN_LINE_ITEM AS b
ON a.RTL_TRAN_ID = b.RTL_TRANS_ID
JOIN TRN_TRANSACTION AS x 
ON x.RTL_TRANS_ID = a.RTL_TRAN_ID
WHERE a.PROMOTION_ID IN (51)
AND b.lineitm_typcode = 'sale'
AND b.item_base_unit_price <> b.item_unit_price
ORDER BY a.RTL_TRAN_ID

SELECT 
SUM(b.ITEM_QUANTITY) * SUM(b.ITEM_BASE_UNIT_PRICE) - SUM(b.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT) 
AS 'Discount Given' 
FROM CMP_PROMO_TRAN_RESULT AS a
JOIN TRN_LINE_ITEM AS b 
ON a.RTL_TRAN_ID = b.RTL_TRANS_ID
WHERE a.PROMOTION_ID IN (51)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "for each row"? Just guessing here; do you want to compute `item_quantity * item_base_unit_price - item_extended_amount` for each row, and THEN get the sum of all the results? If so, `select sum(item_quantity * item_base_unit_price - item_extended_amount)`. The aggregate function `sum()` can be used on any row-level expression, not just on column names.

Comment: No, I'm looking to compute each row and end it at that, I'm not looking to get the sum of all results. Thanks for that information, still learning SQL.

Comment: OK, then that's Lee's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `SUM()`, you are telling MySQL to **aggregate** data of the same group into one number.  There will be an implicit `GROUP BY` added if you don't already one.

In your case, it seems like you do NOT want to aggregate.  Then you should rewrite
your query to something like this (i.e. just drop the `SUM()` aggregation).

**Updated query** (with more columns supporting debugging)

```
SELECT 
    b.ITEM_QUANTITY
    , b.ITEM_BASE_UNIT_PRICE
    , b.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT 
    , b.ITEM_QUANTITY * b.ITEM_BASE_UNIT_PRICE - b.ITEM_EXTENDED_AMT 
        AS 'Discount Given' 
FROM 
    CMP_PROMO_TRAN_RESULT AS a
    JOIN TRN_LINE_ITEM AS b 
        ON a.RTL_TRAN_ID = b.RTL_TRANS_ID
WHERE a.PROMOTION_ID IN (51)
```

Comment: I don't believe my math is adding up correctly on it. I'm trying to basically run this formula: (var1*var2)-var3

Comment: @mediaquery -- For each `PROMOTION_ID` in a (`CMP_PROMO_TRAN_RESULT`), how many `RTL_TRAN_ID` can there be? And is there only one row in b (`TRN_LINE_ITEM`) with the same `RTL_TRAN_ID`? If so, then the `WHERE` (in your original query and mine) would cause the result set to have only one row.  Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Your suggested code outputs it in the correct format., but the math is off. I had an excel sheet with a function [(var1*var2)-var3] in order to get the discount given but the same row in the first statement doesn't sum correctly.

Comment: Try my updated query above and see what the extra columns tell you.